# How to add TypeScript type safety to my redux action?

Tags: typescript, redux, type-safety

I'm writing my application in TypeScript and I'm using Redux to keep track of my app state.  My redux store state looks something like this:

```
interface AppState {
  readonly grid : IGridSettings;
  readonly selected : ISelectedSettings;
  [key : string] : IGridSettings | ISelectedSettings;
}

interface IGridSettings {
  readonly extents : number;
  readonly isXY : boolean;
  readonly isXZ : boolean;
  readonly isYZ : boolean;
  readonly spacing : number;
  [key : string] : number | boolean;
}

interface ISelectedSettings {
  readonly bodyColor : number;
  readonly colorGlow : number;
  readonly lineColor : number;
  readonly selection : number[] | undefined;
  [key : string] : number | number[] | undefined;
}
```

I created the following action to let me update the store however the **setPropertyValue** function is not ideal since it has no type safety!

```
//How to add type safety to this function?
const setPropertyValue = ( property : string[], value : any ) : SetPropertyValueAction => ( {
  type: 'SET_PROPERTY_VALUE',
  payload: {
    property,
    value,
  }
} );

interface SetPropertyValueAction extends Action {
  type : string;
  payload : {
    property : string[];
    value : any;
  };
}
```

I can use this action in my code this way:

```
setPropertyValue( ['grid', 'extents'], 100 );
```

This works, but since there is no type safety in the setPropertyValue function there is nothing restricting me from feeding invalid values into the function like this:

```
setPropertyValue( ['grid', 'size'], 100 ); //invalid since IGridSettings doesn't have a 'size' property
setPropertyValue( ['grid', 'isXY'], -1 ); //value should be a boolean not a number
setPropertyValue( ['selected', 'bodyColor'], '255' ); //value should be a number not a string
```

Is there a way to rewrite the setPropertyValue function so that it only accepts arguments that are valid for the property name found in **AppState**. Also the value passed in must correspond to the correct type for the selected property.

Perhaps using a string array for the **property** to change is not ideal but I don't know of a better way to target only the properties that are available in AppState.

Comment: Are the index sigantures necessary for your use case or did you just add them to allow indexing ? (ex: `[key : string] : IGridSettings | ISelectedSettings;`)

Comment: I needed to add the index signatures to get rid of an error message somewhere along the way.  Without them, the TypeScript code would not compile for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the index signature then there is no way to validate the keys of the type (since after all the index signature would mean the class in indexable by any key, so any key would be valid)

To validate taht a string is a key of a type we can use the `keyof` operator, in conjuction with some generic type parameters (to capture the actual key passed in)

```
interface AppState {
  readonly grid : IGridSettings;
  readonly selected: ISelectedSettings;
}

interface IGridSettings {
  readonly extents : number;
  readonly isXY : boolean;
  readonly isXZ : boolean;
  readonly isYZ : boolean;
  readonly spacing: number;

}

interface ISelectedSettings {
  readonly bodyColor : number;
  readonly colorGlow : number;
  readonly lineColor : number;
  readonly selection : number[] | undefined;
}

const setPropertyValue = <KApp extends keyof AppState, KAppProp extends keyof AppState[KApp]>( property : [KApp, KAppProp], value : AppState[KApp][KAppProp] ) : SetPropertyValueAction => ( {
  type: 'SET_PROPERTY_VALUE',
  payload: {
    property,
    value,
  }
} );

interface SetPropertyValueAction {
  type : string;
  payload : {
    property : PropertyKey[];
    value : any;
  };
}

setPropertyValue( ['grid', 'extents'], 100 );
setPropertyValue( ['grid', 'size'], 100 ); //err
setPropertyValue( ['grid', 'isXY'], -1 ); //err
setPropertyValue( ['selected', 'bodyColor'], '255' );// err
```

Comment: In the interface SetPropertyValueAction, you say that **property** is of type **PropertyKey[]**  What is **PropertyKey** and how is that defined?

Comment: should **SetPropertyValueAction** 's **value** also be something other than **any**?

Comment: `PropertyKey` is defined in lib.d.ts (the default ts library) it's just any key (a key can be `string  | number | symbol`)

Comment: @MarekKnows.com I could be .. but you would need to add generics to `SetPropertyValueAction` I can provide a sample of what that would look like

Comment: thanks, I'll give this a try and see if the compiler complains about me removing the index signature.

Comment: I have the setPropertyValueAction interface and setPropertyValue function working now, however the redux reducer now needs to cast an Action to a setPropertyValueAction **generic** which I can't get to work.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54048358/typescript-how-to-cast-a-generic-object