# TypeScript: How to cast a generic object?

Tags: typescript, redux, casting, type-safety

I have the following interfaces:

```
interface AppState {
  readonly grid : IGridSettings;
  readonly selected : ISelectedSettings;
}

interface IGridSettings {
  readonly extents : number;
  readonly isXY : boolean;
  readonly isXZ : boolean;
  readonly isYZ : boolean;
  readonly spacing : number;
}

interface ISelectedSettings {
  readonly bodyColor : number;
  readonly colorGlow : number;
  readonly lineColor : number;
  readonly selection : number[] | undefined;
}

interface Action<T = any> {
  type: T
}

interface SetPropertyValueAction<KAction extends keyof AppState, KActionProp extends keyof AppState[KAction]> extends Action {
  type : string;
  payload : {
    property : [KAction, KActionProp];
    value : IUserActions[KAction][KActionProp];
  };
}
```

Eventually my redux reducer gets called when the setPropertyValue function is emitted:

```
const setPropertyValue = <KAction extends keyof AppState, KActionProp extends keyof AppState[KAction]>( property : [KAction, KActionProp], value : AppState[KAction][KActionProp] ) : SetPropertyValueAction<KAction, KActionProp> => ( {
  type: 'SET_PROPERTY_VALUE',
  payload: {
    property,
    value,
  }
} );

function myReducer( state : AppState = INITIAL_STATE, a : Action ) : AppState {
  switch( a.type ) {
    case 'SET_PROPERTY_VALUE': {
      const action = a as SetPropertyValueAction; //  <- error here
      return createNewState( state, action.payload.property, action.payload.value );
    }
  }
  return states;
}
```

The problem that I'm having is I don't know how to fix the cast from Action to SetPropertyValueAction.  TypeScript tells me the error is:

```
Generic type 'SetPropertyValueAction<KAction, KActionProp>' requires 2 type argument(s).
```

I tried changing the line of code that has the error to the following:

```
const action = a as SetPropertyValueAction<KAction extends keyof AppState, KActionProp extends keyof AppState[KAction]>;
```

...but this gives me two errors saying 'Cannot find name KAction and KActionProp'

How can I cast an Action object to the generic SetPropertyValueAction ??

This is a follow up question to my other question that has been answered here: [How to add TypeScript type safety to my redux action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54041309/how-to-add-typescript-type-safety-to-my-redux-action)

Comment: You could follow this article: https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/improved-redux-type-safety-with-typescript-2-8-2c11a8062575

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to specify the type parameters for the type. Since we don't really know them, we need something that is compatible with `keyof T` but represent is not an actual key of `T`. `unknown` will not do since it does not satisfy the constraint, the one type we can use is `any` or `never` (which is a subtype of any type)

```
interface AppState {
    readonly grid: IGridSettings;
    readonly selected: ISelectedSettings;
}

interface IGridSettings {
    readonly extents: number;
    readonly isXY: boolean;
    readonly isXZ: boolean;
    readonly isYZ: boolean;
    readonly spacing: number;
}

interface ISelectedSettings {
    readonly bodyColor: number;
    readonly colorGlow: number;
    readonly lineColor: number;
    readonly selection: number[] | undefined;
}

interface Action<T = any> {
    type: T
}

interface SetPropertyValueAction<KAction extends keyof AppState, KActionProp extends keyof AppState[KAction]> extends Action {
    type: string;
    payload: {
        property: [KAction, KActionProp];
        value: AppState[KAction][KActionProp];
    };
}

const setPropertyValue = <KAction extends keyof AppState, KActionProp extends keyof AppState[KAction]>(property: [KAction, KActionProp], value: AppState[KAction][KActionProp]): SetPropertyValueAction<KAction, KActionProp> => ({
    type: 'SET_PROPERTY_VALUE',
    payload: {
        property,
        value,
    }
});
declare const INITIAL_STATE: AppState;
// implementation if necessary     
function createNewState<KAction extends keyof AppState, KActionProp extends keyof AppState[KAction]>(state: AppState, property: [KAction, KActionProp], value: AppState[KAction][KActionProp]): AppState {
    return Object.assign({ ...state }, {
        [property[0]]: Object.assign({ ...state[property[0]] }, {
            [property[1]]: value,
        })
    });
}
function myReducer(state: AppState = INITIAL_STATE, a: Action): AppState {
    switch (a.type) {
        case 'SET_PROPERTY_VALUE': {
            const action = a as SetPropertyValueAction<never, never>; //  we don't know the actual type, never will have to do

            return createNewState(state, action.payload.property, action.payload.value);
        }
    }
    return state;
}
```

Comment: If I want to use the setPropertyValue function like this: **setPropertyValue( property, 10 );** how do I declare the property variable so that it is type safe and the IDE can give me proper autocomplete tips when I'm filling it out with values.  right now I have:  **const property = [ 'grid', 'spacing' ];** which TypeScript gives me an error for since the type is **string[]** not <KAction extends keyof AppState, KActionProp extends keyof AppState[KAction]>

Comment: @MarekKnows.com the const will not preserve the string literal types. to do that, use the `tuple` type here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54070785/how-to-convert-array-of-strings-to-typescript-types/54071129#54071129

Comment: I was also hoping this would work, but it doesn't.  **const property : Array<KAction extends keyof AppState, KActionProp extends keyof AppState[KAction]> = [ 'grid', 'spacing' ];**

Comment: @MarekKnows.com Nope no way to do that, same explanation as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54055578/reflect-and-map-typed-argument-shape-in-typescript/54061822#54061822