# How to convert array of strings to typescript types?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've this array:

```
const arr = ["foo", "bar", "loo"]
```

I need to convert it to a typescript type

```
type arrTyp = "foo" | "bar" | "loo";
```

How can I do this in typescript?

Comment: is the `type` is data type?

Comment: This might be not achievable unless TypeScript support macros.

Comment: @WongJiaHau yes it is, no macros needed, just a plain generic function :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Edit for 3.4 and higher:**

In 3.4 [const assertions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29510) were added, so we can get a string literal type tuple using `as const`:

```
const arr = ["foo", "bar", "loo"] as const

type arrTyp = typeof arr[number]; // "foo" | "bar" | "loo"
```

**Original**

The problem is that `arr` does not preserve the literal types in the array, it will be infered to `string[]`. If you use a function to force the inference of string literal type, extracting the type is a simple affair:

```
function tuple<T extends string[]>(...o: T) {
    return o;
}
const arr = tuple("foo", "bar", "loo")

type arrTyp = typeof arr[number]; // "foo" | "bar" | "loo"
```

The function forces the compiler to infer a tuple of string literals for `arr`. So `arr` will be typed as `["foo", "bar", "loo"]`. We can then use a type query to get a union of the elements in the tuple. You can read more about type queries [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types)

Comment: It works. Can you please explain `typeof arr[number]` a little bit? I've never seen that before. `arr` is now an `Array`. But what is `arr[number]`? 

Comment: @Wajahath added an explanation and a link to the docs for the syntax

Comment: amazing workaround!. Hopefully, there will be a more natural way of doing this in the future

Comment: @Simon updated, with new syntax in 3.4. Thanks for drwing my attention back to this answer . I have a lot of them an can't really update all of them 

Comment: Amazing answer, lovely Typescript :) However, as for the older answer, just out of curiosity, why does exactly "_the function force the compiler to infer a tuple of string literals_"?