# TypeScript: Specify that value must be in Array using spread operator

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to define a type where the favoriteFruit property's value must be an item in options array. Where the options array is dynamic/unknown (making it impossible to use union types "|").

```
const options = ["apple", "orange", "kiwi"]; // Dynamic list that can be modified in the future 

type Person =  {
  name: string;
  favoriteFruit: /* --- val in [...options] --- */
};

const personA:Person = {name: "Jack", favoriteFruit: "apple"}; // OK
const personB:Person = {name: "John", favoriteFruit: "orange"}; // OK
const personC:Person = {name: "Jane", favoriteFruit: "banana"}; // ERROR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for

**[UPDATED]**

```
const options = ["apple", "orange", "kiwi"] as const; // Dynamic list that can be modified in the future 
type optionsType = typeof options[number];

type Person =  {
  name: string;
  favoriteFruit: optionsType;/* --- val in [...options] --- */
};

const personA:Person = {name: "Jack", favoriteFruit: "apple"}; // OK
const personB:Person = {name: "John", favoriteFruit: "orange"}; // OK
const personC:Person = {name: "Jane", favoriteFruit: "banana"}; // ERROR
console.log(personC)
```

you can keep your options list dynamic

[You can test here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)

Answer (score 2):

I found this : [How to convert array of strings to typescript types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54070785/how-to-convert-array-of-strings-to-typescript-types) .

```
const arr = ["foo", "bar", "loo"] as const

type arrTyp = typeof arr[number]; // "foo" | "bar" | "loo"
```